# How to find out why tests are running slow?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

We have Flutter project with a lot of widget tests. It already takes a few minutes for the tests to complete. We run them with:

```
flutter test
```

Is there any way to "profile" the tests and find bottlenecks?

Answer (score 3):

You could scan the verbose test output. It should save timestamps for each test. This can be tedious, but could be a good start to figure out which tests are slow.

```sh
flutter test -v > test_output.txt
```

I agree – it would be nice if there were a "--profile" flag that generate a report for tests.